# How can I compile and run a program designed for an older kernel version (2.6) in a newer kernel (3.16)?

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, ethernet

I'm trying to run a driver for a network card, but it only supports kernels up to 2.6.32. I need to be able to use this piece of hardware to connect to the Internet. The device I'm using is "VIA Technologies VT6105/VT6106S [Rhine-III]".

I know this is possible somehow, because I had the network card working under Linux Mint before I wiped that off for a lighter distro. I've tried both CentOS and Debian with no luck.

Comment: Why looking to compile an old driver, `via-rhine` is available for current kernel 3.16. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: did you try with newer kernels?

Comment: You sure you need the older version? There's a module for kernels 3.2 to 3.13 http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/VIA_RHINE.html

Comment: As usual, give more details. Give the driver name and a link to the driver source, please. Why do you think it doesn't work on more recent kernels? Do you get compile errors? If so, post those errors, please. And so on...

Comment: I don't have this hardware anymore, so this question is no longer valid for me at least, unless someone else were to come around needing help with a VIA Rhine device.